# Which are the requirements of datacenter network for Network Load Balancing to work?

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, vlan

I have two rented dedicated servers and I would like to put them on load balanced cluster configured on Windows 2008 Network Load Balancing.

Since the servers where purchased on different times, they have different network settings  and connect to different gateways.

What is the requirements to put them on a cluster? Put them on the same VLAN will be enough? And what about the network settings, do they need to be connecting to the same gateway?

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is create a third IP address for the cluster and create a matching DNS entry for it, I'm pretty sure that they do need to be in the same subnet and pointing at the same gateway. There's a bunch of proper articles on Technet but it's too sunny outside for me to read them all right now :)

Answer (score 1):

The two nodes need to share one IP and will broadcast/flood your switch with ARP messages of your virtual MAC address for your cluster IP.
Best would be if your switch supported multicast groups to contain the traffic generated by the ARP packets.
So they need to be in the same vlan and subnet.

also it´s good practice to have an alternate path for checking system status (second networkadapter in both nodes) of the clusternodes